# looking for overview and best practice for email to case

Tags: email2case

I am looking to understand the "email to case" functionality offered by `Salesforce.com`, including an overview of what is the best process to use when implementating it and using it on a day-to-day basis. There is very little Salesforce.com managed information available except for configuration information available on the salesforce.com web resources. Ideally I would like a body of knowledge on how to use SfO to create a case from email (I can do this already) and know how best to add emails to a case as the correspendance continues through the lifecycle of the case, how much of this process can be automated?